# Disable List selection but keep childrens functions

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

i got a s:List with a dataprovider and a custom itemrenderer. now my itemrenderer has a button within. 
Every time i choose a item from the list, i get focus on the item, but clicking the button within the item only causes the s:List to select the hole item and wont let me press the button within the item.

is there any solution to disable the "list" selection functionallity but keeping the items within the list enabled / clickable?

as requested, here the code (relevant parts)

**CategoryTree.mxml**

```
<s:List id="data1" name="D1" x="-2000" height="100%" minWidth="600"
    width="{this.width}" dataProvider="{this.childrenResult1.lastResult}"
    itemRenderer="gui.components.Category">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="10" clipAndEnableScrolling="true"
            variableRowHeight="true"></s:VerticalLayout>
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

**Category.mxml**

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:ns="customNS" width="100%" minHeight="200" height="100%"
    maxHeight="410" autoDrawBackground="false" creationComplete="init()"
    updateComplete="update()">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout gap="5" variableColumnWidth="true" />
    </s:layout>
    <s:Group height="100%" width="30">
        <s:BorderContainer depth="0" backgroundAlpha="0.1"
            backgroundAlpha.hovered="0.2" backgroundAlpha.selected="0.4"
            borderVisible="false" height="100%" width="20" buttonMode="true"
            useHandCursor="true" click="{this.previousCategory()}"
            horizontalCenter="0" />
        <ns:BackBtn depth="1" height="30" width="30" useHandCursor="true"
            buttonMode="true" click="{this.previousCategory()}" alpha="0.5"
            alpha.hovered="1" />
    </s:Group>
    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="10">
        <s:Label height="100%" maxHeight="100" maxDisplayedLines="-1"
            fontSize="20" rotation="-90" text="{data.name}" backgroundAlpha="0.6"
            backgroundColor="#6D6D6D" />
        <s:List id="category" height="100%" width="100%"
            itemRenderer="gui.components.ArticleSmall" 
            dataProvider="{this.articles}">
            <s:layout>
                <s:TileLayout clipAndEnableScrolling="false"
                    verticalGap="2" horizontalGap="5" 
                    columnAlign="justifyUsingGap"
                    rowAlign="top" verticalAlign="middle" />
            </s:layout>
        </s:List>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:Group height="100%" width="30">
        <s:BorderContainer backgroundAlpha="0.1"
            backgroundAlpha.hovered="0.2" backgroundAlpha.selected="0.4"
            borderVisible="false" height="100%" width="20" buttonMode="true"
            useHandCursor="true" click="{this.nextCategory()}" 
            horizontalCenter="0" />
        <ns:BackBtn rotation="180" depth="1" height="30" width="30"
            useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" click="{this.nextCategory()}"
            alpha="0.5" alpha.hovered="1" />
    </s:Group>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

**Article.mxml**

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    width="200" height="200" autoDrawBackground="false" depth="0"
    depth.hovered="1" creationComplete="init()">
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="hovered" />
        <s:State name="selected" />
    </s:states>
    <s:BorderContainer useHandCursor="true"
        backgroundAlpha="0" borderVisible="true" width="150" height="150"
        left="0" top="0" borderWeight="2">
        <mx:Image top="12.5" id="article_image" source="assets/dummy.png"
            autoLoad="true" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" scaleContent="true" />
        <mx:Text height="70%" width="100%" left="0.5" top="0.5" right="0.5"
            color="#000000" fontSize="10" text="{data.name}" />
        <mx:Text height="15" width="35%" bottom="0.5" left="0.5"
            color="#000000" fontSize="10" text="{data.prices.price() + '€'}" />
        <s:BorderContainer includeIn="hovered" x="0" y="0"
            width="146" height="146" borderVisible="false" backgroundAlpha="0.2"
            backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
            <s:Button id="btn_add" height="25" width="25" label="Button"
                click="btn_add_clickHandler(event)" skinClass="gui.skins.CartAdd"
                bottom="2" right="29" />
            <s:Button id="btn_del" height="25" width="25" label="Button"
                click="btn_del_clickHandler(event)" skinClass="gui.skins.CartDel"
                bottom="2" right="2" />
        </s:BorderContainer>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

The error happens when clicking the button elements within the article ItemRenderer. Instead of clicking the button, the app selects the "article"-item from the categoy.mxml list.

Comment: Could you share your relevant code (itemrenderer) please?

Comment: I've had buttons inside itemRenderers w/ no issues before.  Please show code.

Comment: @masi It appears you have a list nested inside a list; is that correct?  I question whether that is a good idea or not.

Comment: yes, thats right. but its the only method i found to get two lists with the layout i want. datagroup using tilelayout dosnt work for example, the layout gets messed up. the only container i found to do the job is the list. but if you know any other container that behaves like the s:list does, i'll try it out.

Comment: Did you consider using Tree? http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/spark-tree/

Answer (score 1):

Do you need it to be a List?  Can it just be a DataGroup instead?  The key difference between a List and a DataGroup is that the List has items that are selectable.  If you simply change your code to use a DataGroup, you will still get your item renderers, but loose the selectability.

Does that do what you need?

Comment: well i had a datagroup before and couldnt get it to work the way i want (relative sizeing didnt work out the way i wanted, or if it did the scrollers were messed up) - but i'll give it another shot and report - thanks so far.

Comment: i tryed the following: (see answer)